# Cant call function to button in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding textboxes and buttons programmatically, depending on the count of an array from the result of sql.

I want to call a function(deleteButton_Click) for when each textbox change or when the delete button is pressed for each textbox.

When I press the button, the page reloads (I am using context handler to retrieve some data from a previous page)

here  is a portion of my code, i can include the whole thing if needed. Ideas?

```
for(int i = 0; i < alMakers.Count; i++)
    {
        Label labLabel = new Label();
        labLabel.Text = "Lab" + (i + 1);

        labPanel.Controls.Add(labLabel);

        TextBox labs = new TextBox();
        labs.ID = "lab" + i;
        //labs.TextChanged += deleteLab;
        labPanel.Controls.Add(labs);
        labs.Text = labsList.GetValue(i).ToString();

        Button deleteButton = new Button();
        deleteButton.Text = "Delete";
        deleteButton.Click += deleteButton_Click;
        labPanel.Controls.Add(deleteButton);

        //form1.Controls.Add();


    }
```

here is a portion of my pageload from when I retreive the item from the previous page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string studentID;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Page lastPage = (Page)Context.Handler;
            studentID = ((TextBox)lastPage.FindControl("editStudent")).Text;
            Label1.Text = studentID;
```

EDIT:
My deleteButton_Click function (doesnt do anything as of yet, only changes the text of a label to "Hello")

```
protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = "Hello";
    }
```

Comment: so what do you need?

Comment: So... I thought asp.net webforms button functions worked off of postbacks?

Comment: let's see deleteButton_Click

Comment: The page reloads when I hit any of the buttons I created programatically, doesn't call the function. The deleteButton_Click doesnt do anything, yet, except change a label to say "Hello", just to get it working, but i'll include it.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but your users will thank you if you built this without doing postbacks.  Use some ajax / rest stuff or whatever get's it done without postbacks

Comment: You aren't creating the controls early enough in the [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get wired back up to their events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebForms, control events such as a button click cause the page to completely reload. When that happens, you're starting over from scratch, and must recreate the buttons. It sounds like you may have realized that much already. Additionally, control events in ASP.Net Webforms rely on ViewState. By the time the Page_Load runs, the ViewState has already finished loading. If you wait that long to recreate your buttons, it's too late to wire up the event handler for the button.

In order your click event to fire, you need to create your buttons at an earlier point in the [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), before the ViewState loads, such as Page_Init.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I didnt call the function earlier, but I did just continued adding my delete sql query and assigned it to the buttons, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I have one more quick question. is there an easier way to get the value from previous page before I can load my function to create the buttons/text? declaring the function in the init works only when i hardcode the value that I need from the previous page.

Comment: @ehuizar you can stuff the value in a session variable when processing the first page, and read it when processing subsequent pages.